# Can object reference from thread local variable be shared to other threads safelly?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, session

Consider a scenarion:

```
MySessionObject object = Session.getObject();

//then object is passed to Runnable task.

private class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private final MySessionObject object;

    public SaveVisitorTask(MySessionObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyDao dao = new MyDao();
        MySessionObject savedObject = dao.save(object);
        this.object.setId(savedObject.getId());
    }

}
```

Description:

1. The object retrived from session, e.g. thread local variable.
2. Then it is passed to Runnable task where it persisted asynchronously
3. And then new id is set from saved object to object from thread local variable.

The question is pretty simple - is that code thread safe? It obvious that thread local variable (session) can not 
be shared to threads, but what about references that it holds? Does the statement `this.object.setId(savedObject.getId());` affects original object or not?

**P.S.** If this code is not threadsafe (personally I believe to) could somebody explain why?

Comment: _Any_ object can be shared between threads.  All you have to do is put a reference to the object in a place where more than one thread can see it.  But, wouldn't it kind of defeat the purpose of `ThreadLocal` to store a reference to a shared object in a `ThreadLocal` object?  It certainly would violate the Principle of Least Astonishment.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment

Answer (score 1):

> It obvious that thread local variable (session) can not be shared to
>   threads, but what about references that it holds?

`ThreadLocal` variables are put in a special map in `Thread` class behind the scene and this map maintains the values set. The key of the entry in map is the calling thread itself and value is the value set by "set" method of `ThreadLocal`.

```
public class Thread implements Runnable {

..................
..................
/* ThreadLocal values pertaining to this thread. This map is maintained
     * by the ThreadLocal class. */
ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap threadLocals = null;


}
```

Now the reason they ended up here is because at some point a piece of code ( inside a method) ran which called "set" on the Threadlocal which created an entry in to the threadlocals map with key as the thread and value as the object set.

```
public class ThreadLocal<T> {


.........
.........
 /**
     * Sets the current thread's copy of this thread-local variable
     * to the specified value.  Most subclasses will have no need to
     * override this method, relying solely on the {@link #initialValue}
     * method to set the values of thread-locals.
     *
     * @param value the value to be stored in the current thread's copy of
     *        this thread-local.
     */
    public void set(T value) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
        if (map != null)
            map.set(this, value);
        else
            createMap(t, value);
    }

}
```

So as long as the variable which was set did not escape from the thread method stack, it would be unique to each thread and hence would be thread safe. However if it pointed to some shared variable such as instance variable of class, then there are chances that multiple threads point to same object in the threadlocal map. In that case - it is definitely not thread safe. Also the docs of [Threadlocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) mentions this:

> Each thread holds an implicit reference to its copy of a thread-local 
>   variable as long as the thread is alive and the ThreadLocal   instance
>   is accessible; after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection (unless other
>   references to these copies exist).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Java [Atomic Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html).

An atomic operation will either be completed or not done at all. Other threads will not be able to see the operation "in progress". it will never be viewed in a partially complete state.

Comment: You are absolutelly right, but the question is not about `what to use?`, but `is it works?` and `how it works?` :)

Comment: Final fields, by definition, do not change after construction of the object. If what you really mean is that you want the field to be set once. So I don't think it'll work because you have a setter for a object that was declared with the final keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Statement `this.object.setId(savedObject.getId());` actually affects original object.Because `object` is not retrieved from thread local in other thread but you pass it directly to other thread.

If you call `Session.getObject();` in your second thread then it will return you a thread specific copy of object.